# AutomationPeer.ListenerExists returning true on Windows server 2012

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-server-2012, automationpeer

I have a WPF application that correctly runs on Windows Xp and Windows 7.
When I installed it on a Windows server 2012, I realized that an error occurred dealing with AutomationPeers. Here's part of the stack trace:

> ...
>   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.EnsureChildren()
>   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateChildrenInternal(Int32 invalidateLimit)
>   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateSubtree()
>   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdatePeer(Object arg)
>   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

I had a look inside the source code of the control that raised that exception and I realized that that part of code could only run if calls to the static method:

```
`AutomationPeer.ListenerExists()`
```

return true.

Why on all other systems, calls to

```
`AutomationPeer.ListenerExists()`
```

all return false, while on that windows 2012 server it returns true?

Is there a way to remove those listeners?

Note: my application was built in release mode.

Comment: Note: the component that arose the problem is the Datagrid in "Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)"; I posted a workaround at [link](https://wpf.codeplex.com/workitem/12979);